# Set ASP Grid View row count to specific number

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

The title is not very explanatory but I am wondering if it is possible to set the grid's row count regardless of the rows in the data source, for instance, i want my grid to have 10 rows but my data source only has 5, is there a way for the grid to have those 10 rows, where 5 would be filled but the other 5 would be left blank?

I know it's a weird question and probably it's gonna get lost in SO but can anyone help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this:

```
For i As Integer = 1 To 5
        Dim dr As DataRow = dt.NewRow()
        dt.Rows.Add(dr)
Next
```

Answer (score 1):

Your only way to do this will be to provide 'dummy' data in your data source to make up the requisite number of rows.

Your data that you are binding to will need to accommodate null fields for every cell etc.

Bit of an odd requirement...

Comment: I know it's odd but my objective is to build a printable document and a messed up grid view isn't very helpful for said objective. Anyways thanks for the suggestion :)